# Exception Initializer Error in WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere

Whilst migrating from WebSphere 6.1 to WebSphere 8.5.5, an application throws an ExceptionInitialiserError

On investigation, the URI created from WebSphere 8.5.5. returns
bundleresource://129.fwk1900998897/

But the URI from WebSphere 6.1 the return is 
file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/properties/

This seems to an issue with the xwork from apache.  Any thoughts.

sanj

Comment: Can you add more error stracktrace ?

Comment: Stack Track too large for post, what your email

Comment: If you can put your mail id I can send a test mail to it.

Comment: sanjay.jairam.eu@gmail.com